# Vanilla JS animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Like in the question, I have a code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.link-fade', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var link = this;
$('body').fadeOut(function () {
location.href = link.href;
});
});
```

It is written using the Jquery library, but I want to write it without it (I know you have to use addEventlistener etc. and XHR but I do not know how to use XHR) How to write this code without Jquery?

And here is the CSS code (animation):

```css
body {
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
100% {
opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Comment: No, you do not need to use XMLHttpRequest to make an animation

Comment: I suggest looking into using a css rule for a class with 0 opacity and animation, and then toggling that class using JS. This is the best solution for simple animations imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `transition` and `opacity` CSS properties.

First define the following CSS on your page:

```
body { transition: opacity 400ms }
```

This will ensure that if you change the body's `opacity`, it will have the fade-effect.

By listening to the `transitionend` event, you can perform the expected navigation-action after the transition has ended.

Finally, the event delegation can be done by adding the class check inside the event handler: if the event did not happen on an element of class "link-fade", then just exit the handler:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains("link-fade")) return; 
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = event.target;
    document.body.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
        location.href = link.href;
    });
});
```

NB: `this`, in the event handler, will be `document`. The clicked element is `event.target`.

Comment: Thank you, I've already found the answer, this code is also good, thank you for your help :)

Comment: I tested the code and the code redirect me to /undefinied page... whats wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `link.href` is defined? I tested this code and it worked fine for me. If you can make a fiddle to demonstrate the issue, I'll be glad to look at it.

Comment: The error with the wrong redirection has literally gone away a moment ago, I don't know what happened...

Comment: I have one more idea, but if you use XHR to send requests to the server (I have a dark theme on page and it doesn't look too much when there is a break between loading the other page "white screen") so it's better to use XHR so that this page transition doesn't cause "flash".

Comment: When you have a specific problem of undesired animation effects (flash?) while doing ajax, could you ask a new question about that (tagging with ajax)? It is important to provide example code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Ajax I'm just getting started, flash is called by the browser while loading between pages only I don't know how to implement the request in this code. I mean `location.href = link.href;` here AJAX should appear to "smoothly" load another page (no white background between pages).

[PS]

How to make `classList.contains("link-fade"))` catch every element of `<a>` (I've never had to do with `contains`.)

Comment: Well `location.href =` is not ajax, but plain navigation. And as you asked here, the navigation is only initiated after the animation ends, so it's just making the whole process longer. For doing ajax, look into jQuery's `$.ajax`, or use plain JavaScript's `fetch`. Then you can start the animation immediately *after* you initiate the ajax request. When the ajax request comes back with a response, you can update (parts of) the page with that information. But doing page transitions with ajax, is a whole subject on its own. Please try, and come back with a new question if you have issues.

Comment: I'm sorry to mention it again, but how do you make a script catch all the elements of ``a>` and not like now with a class of `link-fade

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("a")`. Or with jQuery `$("a")`. To get only those that have a `href` attribute: `$("a[href]")`.

Comment: I add `document.querySelectorAll("a")` and the code not work... (`if (!event.target.document.querySelectorAll("a")) return; `)

Comment: It does not return a boolean. It is a nodelist, that could be empty. So inspect the `.length` attribute of it.

Answer (score 1):

Create animation to fadeOut body after click and apply it to body with class `.fade-out-body`, then you can block redirection on click (`e.preventDefault()`) add that class to fadeOut body, wait for animation to finish and then after that you can change the location of the page (like you are doing in jQuery right now). On load you can add animation you wrote above and they should work together (fadeOut after click and fadeIn on load).

```
function fadeOutRedirect(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Add class - it should fade out body */
    document.body.classList.add('fade-out-body');

    /* After 1000ms redirect to the new subpage */
    const newLocation = e.target.src 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        location.href = newLocation;    
    }, 1000);

}

var fadeOutLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.link-fade');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(fadeOutLinks, function (el, i) {
    el.addEventListener('click', fadeOutRedirect);
});
```

This is not a optimal solution - because we don't really load the content just delaying it, but to avoid it you would need to use XHR. But it is a solution similar to that used in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you, I was just thinking overnight that no need to use XHR, the solution helped me understand this code :) Thank you again.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it does not implement the event delegation that the OP had in jQuery. The jQuery version will still handle clicks even if triggered on new content is added later on -- which is the whole idea of doing event delegation. This code will not handle any new content that is added to the document. Secondly, waiting 1000ms is not really waiting for the animation to finish, which is what the jQuery version really does. The actual animation duration depends on load and paint events. Same for `setTimeout`